# String issue for Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, multiprocessing

facing some issues with string parsing and the multiprocessing library. Here is my code, and I also outline the function calls and error.

```
def semi_func(tile):
        with open(tile, 'rb') as f:
           img = Image.open(BytesIO(f.read()))
           resized_im, seg_map = MODEL.run(img)
           vis_segmentation_tiles(str(tile),resized_im, seg_map)
           x = np.unique(seg_map)
           x = x.tolist()
           print("THIS IS X", x)
           ans_tiles[str(tile)] = x
           print(x)
        return ans_tiles
    
def split_tiles_new(image_path, tiledir):
        print("1")
        pool = Pool(processes=5)
        print("2")
        num_tiles = 9
        tiles = image_slicer.slice(image_path, num_tiles, save=False)
        print("3")
        print(tiles)
        image_slicer.save_tiles(tiles, directory=tiledir)
        print(tiles)
        print("TILES ABOEVE")
        
        onlytiles = [os.path.join(tiledir,f) for f in listdir(tiledir) if isfile(join(tiledir, f))]
       
        ans_tiles = {}
        print(onlytiles)
        onlytiles = list(map(str, onlytiles))
        for t in onlytiles:
            print(t)
        for tile in onlytiles:
            print(tile)
            pool.map(semi_func,tile)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(ans_tiles)
        return ans_tiles
```

Here's what I'm feeding in terms of my functions:

```
ans_tiles = split_tiles_new(local_jpg, tiledir)
```

```
local_jpg = 'wheat044146108.jpg'

tiledir = 'tiles044146108'
```

Inside tiledir (the directory), there's a bunch of tiled images:

```
['tiles044146108/_03_02.png', 'tiles044146108/_03_01.png', 'tiles044146108/_02_02.png', 'tiles044146108/_01_01.png', 'tiles044146108/_03_03.png', 'tiles044146108/_01_02.png', 'tiles044146108/_02_01.png', 'tiles044146108/_02_03.png', 'tiles044146108/_01_03.png']
```

That's what is in the variable 'onlytiles'.

But my issue is this error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "serve_wh.py", line 128, in semi_func
    with open(tile, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 't'
"""
```

I am not sure why it is doing further slicing of the string? Any idea what I can do to ensure it just grabs each file from 'onlyfiles' list separately in this?

Answer (score 2):

Your iterable is a filename string thats why it's trying to open file with name `t`. Check [Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) second argument.

```
pool.map(semi_func,tile)
```

You should use

```
pool.map(semi_func,onlytiles)
```

Without the for loop so that it iterates over the list rather than string.

Comment: I try this and it keeps timing out

Comment: @mike0494 Please tell at which portion it is stuck. You can check that by adding lots of print statements. This change will fix the filename not found issue. But the timeout one is different.